# Editing a object of a tree table

Tags: javascript, arrays, model, sapui5, treetable

I have a question to a tree table from SAPUI5. Here is my JSFiddle: (https://jsfiddle.net/vazOrt/5L6e97wj/11/)

I have in the last node, objects of clothing. I want in the change-function of the inputfield, to change the propertie "change" to true.
This is the object
`{"name": "Red T-shirt", "amount": 16.99, "currency": "USD", "size": "s", "change": false}`

If the user change the size in the inputfield i want to be update the object
`{"name": "Red T-shirt", "amount": 16.99, "currency": "USD", "size": "s", "change": true}`

But i dont find any solution to came from the tree table to the object from the model. Have someone a idea how i can update the property of the object?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to update your changed object's actual `change` property in that nested array. Additionally because you have two way binding, simply the accessed data can be updated as below.

So the working `changeState` function:

```
changeState: function(e) {
      const view = this.getView();
      const model = view.getModel();
      const data = model.getData();

      const fieldName = e.mParameters.id;
      const elem = e.oSource.oParent.mAggregations.cells.find(function(f) {
        return f.sId === fieldName;
      });            
      const state = elem.oParent._oNodeState;
      const groups = state.groupID.split('/').filter(function(a) { return a !== '' });
      const path = groups[groups.length - 1];
      const fullPath = path.split('_');

      let stringPath = 'catalog.clothing';

      for (let i = 0; i < fullPath.length; i++) {
        stringPath += '[' + fullPath[i] + ']'
      }

      const targetObject = Object.byString(data, stringPath);
      targetObject.change = true;

      console.log('changed', data);
}
```

Additional function what you need to add to your code - for this the credit is going to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key):

```
Object.byString = function(o, s) {
    s = s.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1'); // convert indexes to properties
    s = s.replace(/^\./, '');           // strip a leading dot
    var a = s.split('.');
    for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var k = a[i];
        if (k in o) {
            o = o[k];
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

Please find the JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Ln31qtor/

I hope that helps!